# Hide application PlayStore

Tags: android, release, hidden, invisible

I just finished my first Android application and I want to release it in order to put ads on it (with Unity Ads) but I do not want people to see or download it. Is it possible to make it invisible or hide?

Comment: Put it on Alpha or Beta.

Comment: I just checked the Unity [docs](http://unityads.unity3d.com/help/Documentation%20for%20Publishers/Integration-Guide-for-Android) and it doesn't seem like you need to publish your app before receiving ads. I don't understand what a published app would have over an unpublished app that Unity requires in order to serve you ads.

Comment: it looks easier to put ads on it when it's published...

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

You can release it as a [beta](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html#alpha-beta) and just invite no one.

Comment: Or only click the `save as draft` button and not the `publish` button.

Comment: Sorry, i am beginner : how do you do that ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `developer console` just beside the Green **Published** tag, you will find a gray **Unpublish app** link. Simply click on that. You can republish it any time you want.

[image]